# Segmentation fault (code dumped) error in gfortran

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, fortran90

I am comparing two files and finding the colocated points using Fortran. Code works perfectly fine on my laptop with gfortran version 10.2.0, while I keep this code on my ssh server (ssh used gfortran 4.8.5; also tried with version 8.3.1), it works good for most of the iteration but provides the following error for the few iterations:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F750B7F8697
#1  0x7F750B7F8CDE
#2  0x7F750ACF33FF
#3  0x402493 in MAIN__ at 1_myd_trmm_coloc.f90:?
1a_myd_trmm_coloc.sh: line 10: 42668 Segmentation fault  (core dumped) ./1_myd_trmm_coloc.out < infile
```

Following is my Fortran code:

```
    IMPLICIT NONE
    Character*180::mydf,trmmf,outf
    integer::my,mmn,md,mh,mmi,ms,mat
    real::mla,mlo,ma412,ma470,ma550,ma660,mae
    integer::ty,tmn,td,th,ic,i,j,i1,j1,i22,j22,n
    real::tla,tlo,tpr

    real,allocatable::m(:,:),t(:,:)
    real::delat,delon,c,a,dist,rlon1,rlon2,rlat1,rlat2
    real::mtim,ttim,maxttim,minttim,minlat,maxlat,minlon,maxlon

    real,dimension(100000)::ds,ala,alo
    integer,dimension(100000)::ay,amn,ad,ah,ami,as,aat
    real,dimension(100000)::a412,a470,a550,a660,aae,ppr

    read*,mydf
    read*,trmmf
    read*,outf

    open(11,file=mydf,status='old')
        i=0
 5      read(11,*,end=90,err=80)my,mmn,md,mh,mmi,ms,mla,mlo, &
             ma412,ma470,ma550,ma660,mae,mat
        i=i+1
 80     goto 5
 90     close(11)
            allocate(m(i,14))
        open(11,file=mydf,status='old')
        i1=0
  6     read(11,*,end=91,err=81)my,mmn,md,mh,mmi,ms,mla,mlo, &
            ma412,ma470,ma550,ma660,mae,mat
        i1=i1+1
            m(i1,1)=my ; m(i1,2)=mmn ; m(i1,3)=md
            m(i1,4)=mh ; m(i1,5)=mmi ; m(i1,6)=ms
            m(i1,7)=mla ; m(i1,8)=mlo ; m(i1,9)=ma412
            m(i1,10)=ma470 ; m(i1,11)=ma550 ; m(i1,12)=ma660
            m(i1,13)=mae ; m(i1,14)=mat
  81        goto 6
  91    close(11)

    open(12,file=trmmf,status='old')
        j=0
  15        read(12,*,end=190,err=180)ty,tmn,td,th,tla,tlo,tpr
        j=j+1
  180       go to 15
  190   close(12)
            allocate(t(j,7))
    open(12,file=trmmf,status='old')
        j1=0
  16        read(12,*,end=191,err=181)ty,tmn,td,th,tla,tlo,tpr
        j1=j1+1
            t(j1,1)=ty ; t(j1,2)=tmn ; t(j1,3)=td
            t(j1,4)=th ; t(j1,5)=tla ; t(j1,6)=tlo
            t(j1,7)=tpr ;
  181       go to 16
  191   close(12)

    open(51,file=outf,status='unknown')

    do  i22=1,i
                n=0;    ds=-999.0
                ala=-999.0;alo=-999.0;a412=-999.0;a470=-999.0
                a550=-999.0;a660=-999.0;aae=-999.0;aat=-999;
                ppr=-999.0;
                ic=0
        do j22=1,j
            if(t(j22,1).eq.m(i22,1).and.t(j22,2).eq.m(i22,2).and. &
                    t(j22,3).eq.m(i22,3)) then
                    minlat=t(j22,5)-0.125; maxlat=t(j22,5)+0.125
                    minlon=t(j22,6)-0.125; maxlon=t(j22,6)+0.125
                    mtim=m(j22,4)+(m(j22,5)/60)+(m(j22,6)/3600)
                    ttim=t(j22,4)
                    minttim=ttim-0.5; maxttim=ttim+0.5

                if(m(i22,7).ge.minlat.and.m(i22,7).le.maxlat.and. &
                   m(i22,8).ge.minlon.and.m(i22,8).le.maxlon.and. &
                     mtim.ge.minttim.and.mtim.le.maxttim) then

                        rlat1=(m(i22,7)*3.141592657)/180.0; rlat2=(t(j22,5)*3.141592657)/180.0
                        rlon1=(m(i22,8)*3.141592657)/180.0; rlon2=(t(j22,6)*3.141592657)/180.0
                        delat=rlat2-rlat1; delon=rlon2-rlon1
                        a=SIN(delat/2.0)**2+(COS(rlat1)*COS(rlat2)*SIN(delon/2.0)**2)
                        c=2.0*atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a))
                        dist=6378136.300*c
                        ic=ic+1
                        ! print*,ic
                        ds(ic)=dist
                        ala(ic)=m(i22,7)
                        alo(ic)=m(i22,8)
                        ay(ic)=m(i22,1); amn(ic)=m(i22,2); ad(ic)=m(i22,3)
                        ah(ic)=m(i22,4); ami(ic)=m(i22,5); as(ic)=m(i22,6)
                        a412(ic)=m(i22,9); a470(ic)=m(i22,10)
                        a550(ic)=m(i22,11); a660(ic)=m(i22,12)
                        aae(ic)=m(i22,13); aat(ic)=m(i22,14)
                        ! py(ic)=t(j22,1); pmn(ic)=t(j22,2); pd(ic)=t(j22,3)
                        ! ph(ic)=t(j22,4); pla(ic)=t(j22,5); plo(ic)=t(j22,6)
                        ppr(ic)=t(j22,7)
                    end if
            end if
        end do
        if (ic>0)then
            write(51,111)minval(ds,ds.ne.-999.0), ay(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)),  &
                amn(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)), ad(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)),      &
                ah(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)), ami(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)),      &
                as(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)), ala(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)),      &
                alo(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)), a412(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)),    &
                a470(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)), a550(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)),   &
                a660(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)), aae(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0)),    &
                aat(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999)), ppr(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999.0))
            n=n+1
            ! print*,n
        end if
        end do
  111           format(f16.6,1x,i4,1x,5(1x,i2.2),1x,2(1x,f8.3),1x,5(1x,f6.3),1x,i2,1x,f8.3)
            deallocate(m)
            deallocate(t)
        close(51)
  end
```

I am looking for a mistake in the code.
Here are the sample data files:

File-1

```
    2008  04 06 09 27 03    10.250   50.250    0.303    0.303    0.303    0.303    0.000   1
    2008  04 06 09 27 03    10.500   50.500    0.247    0.247    0.247    0.247    0.000   1
    2008  04 06 09 27 03    10.750   50.500    0.219    0.180    0.142    0.111    1.500   2
    2008  04 06 09 27 03    11.000   50.500    0.157    0.129    0.102    0.079    1.500   2
    2008  04 06 09 27 46    11.250   50.000    0.064    0.053    0.042    0.032    1.500   2
    2008  04 06 09 27 46    11.250   50.250    0.151    0.124    0.098    0.076    1.500   2
    2008  04 06 09 27 46    11.500   50.250    0.129    0.106    0.083    0.065    1.500   2
```

File-2

```
    2008 4 6 6 9.875 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 10.125 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 10.375 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 10.625 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 10.875 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 11.125 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 11.375 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 11.625 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 11.875 29.125 0
    2008 4 6 6 12.125 29.125 0
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. When using gfortran, compile your code with flags `-g -Wall -fcheck=all` to get more useful backtrace and to get checks for certain coding errors. I cannot see any `IMPLICIT NONE` in your code. Use it for all your codes and use it every time when asking others to check your code. It is extremely important.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did `-g -Wall -fcheck=all` to get backtrace but it doesn't have any warning. As I said, code works perfectly for gfortran version higher than 5.x but it just creates an issue just for few iterations with the gfortran version 4.8. I forget to add `IMPLICIT NONE` here. Thank you for point out.

Comment: So, don't use versions older than 5.x!  There have been a few thousand changes and fixes to compiler.  Or, beat your head against your desk.

Comment: If gfortran-10.2 is available, I think it's probably useful to try the "-Wall -Wextra" options (which gives me a lot of warnings like real vs real comparison, real to integer assignment, too large arrays for stack, etc, etc)

Comment: The point was that you should have posted the better backtrace here. Please [edit] your questoion and insert it. However, I agree you should use a more current GCC version.  Be aware that you can always install you own gcc in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have that version available to test, but I suspect your issue stems from aat(minloc(ds,ds.ne.-999)) - you are testing a real ds against an integer -999, that is rarely a good idea. In addition(Just FYI, Testing eq among reals is only reliable in a few circumstances.

Note posting a sample dataset would help in further diagnosis

Comment: According to the rules of Fortran the rational expression is fine.  From Fortran 2018, 10.1.5.5.1: _In the numeric relational operation
       x1 rel-op x2
if the types or kind type parameters of x1 and x2 differ, their values are converted to the type and kind type parameter of the expression x1 + x2 before evaluation._

Comment: But the question is does gfortran 4.8 handle it that way

Comment: I think this should not matter because a code works fine for most of the iterations just a few of them only provide an error. If this should be a problem then it has to provide an error for all the iterations.

Comment: @Cocofalco, gfortran has been able to do mixed-mode arithmetic for a very long time.  It's actually one of the easy parts of a compiler to implement and get right.  You can verify the conversion with -fdump-tree-original.

Comment: @Piyushkumar Patel - still no sample dataset?

Comment: @Cocofalco I edited my question with the sample datasets. Also, I tried to run this code on ssh server with gfortran version 8.3.1 but still providing same error for few iterations.

Comment: @Piyushkumar Patel - just a thought, you dont have multiple processes trying to write to the same file here do you? Thats a common issue on webservers - I assume when you say you are having troubles on only some iterations, you are getting some output  on the failed iteration, just not complete.